# Сборка ресурсов проекта в jar Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

Собираю проект с помощью Gradle. При этом из resources в jar входит только META-INF. Как собрать остальные ресурсы в исходный jar?

В resources находятся:

```
META-INF
somefolder
somefile.yml
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'cathub'
version '1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://repo.nukkitx.com/snapshot"
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'cn.nukkit:nukkit:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.5'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.3.6.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.0.13.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '5.3.6.Final'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "ru.cathub.Cathub"
    }
}
```

Comment: а где находится директория resources?

Comment: src/main/resources

Comment: а как вы смотрите что попало в jar?

Comment: Открыл jar архиватором. Да и при запуске проекта получаю ошибку - файл не найден.

Comment: что-то не договариваете.. все  добавляется по вышеуказанному примеру

Comment: впервые работаю с gradle. Все делал по документации. И почему то конфиг hibernate создаётся, а остальные ресурсы нет.